# Cheerio. Can't get data inside TRY body after handling error of another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

There is a code like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
let data = null;



const parseNewCorporations = async (iter) => {
  
  let link2 = 'https://www.finanzen.net/aktien/' + iter.finanzen_net + '-aktie';
  try{
    await axios.get(link2)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(res => {
        
        let html = res;
        
        $ = cheerio.load( html, { decodeEntities: false } );
        let bigData = iter;
        
        let price = $('div.snapshot-headline div.col-sm-7 div.row.quotebox:first-child div.col-xs-5.col-sm-4.text-sm-right.text-nowrap').text();
        let currency = $('div.snapshot-headline div.col-sm-7 div.row.quotebox:first-child div.col-xs-5.col-sm-4.text-sm-right.text-nowrap span').text();
        price = price.replace(currency, '').replace(',', '.');
      })
  }
  
  catch(e){
    console.log(e.message, ', id =', iter.id, ", finanzen_net = "+iter.finanzen_net);
    await getAdditionPriceBilanzGuv(iter);
  }
};



const getAdditionPriceBilanzGuv = async (iter) => {
  
  //console.log('111', iter); // **here the code works correctly**
  
  let link = 'https://www.finanzen.net/bilanz_guv/'+ iter.finanzen_net;
  
  try{
    await axios.get(link)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(res => {
        
        console.log('getAdditionPriceBilanzGuv', iter);
        // **here the code works NOT correctly**
        
      })
  }
  
  catch(e){
    if(e.message == 'Request path contains unescaped characters'){
      console.log('Request path contains unescaped characters');
      console.log({paramSubLink: iter.finanzen_net, corporations_id: iter.id});
    }
    else{
      console.log('paramCorporationsId: ', iter.id);
      //console.log('err- ', e);
    }
  }
};



function getApiData(){
  
  // get request
      return axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/invest/daily.php" , {
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}



async function new_corporations() {
    data = await getApiData();
    let ii = 1;
    for (let iter of data.new_corporations) {
        //await parseNewCorporations(iter);
        
        ii++;
        await setTimeout(function(){
            parseNewCorporations(iter);
        }, ii*3000);
        

    }
    //console.log(arrayCurrency);
}


new_corporations();
```

After calling the `parseNewCorporations ()` function, the `catch ()` exception is triggered as a result of which
the corresponding messages can be seen in the console. 
 
The problem is that when this error appears, you need to run the following function `getAdditionPriceBilanzGuv ()` with the `iter` parameter, and inside the body of`try {}`you need to get this parameter, which cannot be done. 
At the very beginning (outside the body of `try {}`) of this function (where it is indicated by a comment that the code works), it is possible to get this parameter. 
Question: 
What am I missing and how can I get this parameter in a newly called function inside the body of `try {}`? 
If it is impossible to do this, what alternative implementations can be for solving this problem?

P.S. In this case, a parsing library is used [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use async / await, you don't want `then`s

```
let res = await axios.get(link2)
let $ = cheerio.load(res.data)
```